# Scheduled incremental crawl behavior on a paused crawl question

Tags: sharepoint

Quick question, I've started by mistake an incremental crawl on one of my content source. I've then pause it so it doesn't impact users.

Will it resume on the next scheduled incremental crawl or I need to resume it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this should resume in the next schedule but even though incremental crawl is scheduled, we can run the incremental crawl anytime in between, there is no harm in that - actually that is the purpose of incremental crawl. In between the crawl scheduling - if we want to bring some items in the search result on demand based on the business needs we can run the incremental crawl manually anytime:-)